# WPF Toolkit Chart control binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I have a data table. This data table is processed through a class and results in a set of DataSeries. These consist of a name and list of DataPoint. DataPoint contains X and Y values, along with a tool tip. The user can chose 1 grouping level (which results in one DataSeries) or two grouping levels (which results in many DataSeries). I want to be able to bind these DataSeries to my WPF toolkit chart. I made a wrapper class which converts the DataSeries to BarSeries or ColumnSeries, depending on the type the user selected. But when i try to bind it using

```
`<Chart Series={Binding Series} />`
```

I get an error saying `A 'Binding' can not be used on collection oc type 'Chart'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Series is not a dependency property. Therefore i cant bind to it. Someone post this so i can mark it as an answer :)

Comment: You can answer your own question simply by posting an answer below and then marking it. Or are you just being generous? :)

Comment: lol consider it generosity. I dont like answering my own questions :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, fella.

The solution is pretty obvious ;)

**Series is not a dependency property. Therefore you cannot bind to it.**